# Android: Application ID 1234567890 is not associated with package com.abc.def

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to connect to Google Play Services / Google Play Games. When attempting that, I am seeing the error: `E/GameAgent(12345): Application ID 1234567890 is not associated with package com.abc.def. Check the application ID in your manifest.`

*numbers and package name were changed here*

The normal package name, given in my manifest file as `app_id` equals to the one I find on top of the Google Play Developer Console under `Google Play Games [Controller Icon] -> Infos about Game`

My Application is not released, but uploaded to Google Play as draft.
Is there anything else I need to modify?

Comment: The applicationID in your manifest should be the same as your package name, same as the one you've linked in your Google Play Developer console. If you're using Android Studio, check your build.gradle too.

Comment: I got the problem myself now, I thought the .apk was signed automatically when I hit "Run", but I needed to do it manually... I feel stupid now.

Comment: did you have to "publish" your linked app before it would successfully log in to play games ?

Comment: does the app have to uploaded to play store (at least as alpha or beta) before it'll sign in ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere It's been almost two years since I had that issue, but reading my comment up there, I guess I just had to sign the .apk